# How to know row index of removed row

Tags: extjs

I have one extJS grid. I am removing one row from grid. Is there anyway by which I can find which row I am removing from grid after removing operation done.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the `remove` event of the store associated to your grid.
From the ExtJs 6.2.1 documentation [remove event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-remove).

> Fired when one or more records have been removed from this Store.

So you could do the following.

```
var store = grid.getStore();
store.on('remove', function(store, records, index, isMove){
    // your logic
});
```